# CodePipeline does not have a notification for pipeline stopped?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

We are handling CodePipeline notifications and monitoring the progress of pipelines, recording them in DynamoDb.  The normal pipeline flow works great, BUT, we have a scenario where if the pipeline is manually stopped, or stopped/abandoned, there is NO notification sent out.  Therefore, the pipeline get stuck in IN_PROGRESS on our end, because we have no trigger to finalize the process.

There is a Pipeline cancelled notification but that doesn't apply to the scenario where the pipeline is stopped.

> [CANCELED - The pipeline execution was canceled because the pipeline structure was
> updated.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html#detect-state-events-stage-stopped:%7E:text=Description-,CodePipeline,-Pipeline%20Execution%20State)

The interesting part is that the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html#detect-state-events-pipeline-stopping:%7E:text=execution%20is%20currently%20running.-,STOPPED,-The%20stopping%20process%20is) shows there is a STOPPED and STOPPING notification, but I have yet to see how to configure the pipeline to use it.

Is there any way of detecting the STOPPED condition?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided makes use of EventBridge. In EventBridge, you can configure a rule to listen to `STOPPED`event. Here is an simple rule that works for me:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.codepipeline"],
  "detail-type": ["CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

The rule can send notification to SNS as well.